# Error when switching to iframe with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

Currently I'm attemping to switch from my default content, to the only iframe in the website. I don't know if it's how the site is coded, but I can't access via DOM any element.

This is the HTML structure of the site:
[image: HTML structure of scrapped site]

XPATH of site is `//*[@id="iframeBody"]` (When I paste this in the element inspector, I get the correct iframe). So, if I try to switch using `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`, this is the output:

```
try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iframeBody' and @name='body']")))
except Exception as e:
        print(e)

>>> Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
>>>(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

I also tried creating an iframe element variable, finding it via ID and XPATH and then I've used switch_to(element). Getting the same result. When I print this variable, the element is actually found:

```
# Also tried finding with id
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id='iframeBody')
print(element)

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9184691b1fdcccc15dd36bbcb914ac8b", element="1ef77729-8a6e-4d3c-98bd-c95878437585")>
```

But when I try to switch to this iframe, I get the same result as above.
For some reason, this site is not letting me use the DOM data, actually, when I try to click a button I need to use action chains, because I get the same error.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: doesn't seem like you should get a javascript error when using a webdriverwait... that's kind of odd.  Include a fuller version of the code.  Try/catch the call and post the exception from the webdriver if any...

Comment: I've updated my question right now with try and catch.

Comment: not sure of syntax for python there... but it looks like it's expecting a webelement.  (instead of By locator) frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt has overloaded constructors... https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(int)

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `enough time` before switching ?

also, you could directly `switch` as well:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("iframeBody"))
```